# Why does knockout template binding stop working after manually reordering - and reverting - dom items?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am using a knockout foreach (more specifically, `template: { foreach: items }`) binding to display a list of elements.
I then proceed to take the following actions:

1. Swap the first and second elements of the observable array. I see the changes reflected on screen, as expected.
2. Repeat the previous action to revert to the initial state. Again, this works as expected.
3. Now, swap the first and second DOM elements. I see the changes reflected on screen, as expected.
4. Repeat the previous action to revert to the initial state. Again, this works as expected.

Even though we have manually tampered with the DOM, we have reverted to exactly the initial state, without invoking knockout during the DOM tampering. This means the state is restored to the last time knockout was aware of it, so it should look to knockout as if nothing ever changed to begin with.
However, if I perform the first action again, that is, swap the first two elements in the array, the changes are not reflected on screen.

Here is a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/k7u5wep9/.

I know that manually tampering with the DOM managed by knockout is a bad idea and that it can lead to undefined behaviour. This is unfortunately unavoidable in my situation due to third party code. What stumps me is that, even after reverting the manual edits to the *exact* initial state, knockout still does not work as expected.

My question is: what causes this behaviour?
And then, how does one work around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there is nothing magical happening here. The mistake I made was to only consider elements instead of all nodes. The knockout template binding keeps a record of all nodes when reordering, not just elements.

Before manually editing the DOM, the child nodes of the template binding are:

`NodeList(6) [text, div, text, text, div, text]`.

After manually swapping the first two *elements* using `parent.insertBefore(parent.children[1], parent.children[0])`, this turns into:

`NodeList(6) [text, div, div, text, text, text]`.

Repeating the action yields:

`NodeList(6) [text, div, div, text, text, text]`.

Although this is identical to the initial state when only referring to *elements*, it is quite different when referring to all *nodes*.

The solution now becomes clear. One way to perform a proper manual swap is to replace

`parent.insertBefore(parent.children[1], parent.children[0]);`

with

```
let nexts = [parent.children[0].nextSibling, parent.children[1].nextSibling];
parent.insertBefore(parent.children[1], nexts[0]);
parent.insertBefore(parent.children[0], nexts[1]);
```

as seen in https://jsfiddle.net/k7u5wep9/2/.

Obviously more care has to be taken when there are no text nodes before/after, but the idea remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a `with: items` around your `foreach`, it at least keeps working but requires double click if dom order != array order .. might get you on track atleast, maybe you can re-order the ko-array inside the dom function to keep their 'orders' in sync?

```js
let vm = {
  items: ko.observableArray(['item1', 'item2']),
  reorder_array() {
    vm.items([vm.items()[1], vm.items()[0]]);
  },
  reorder_dom() {
    let parent = document.querySelector('#items');
    parent.insertBefore(parent.children[1], parent.children[0]);
    vm.reorder_array();
  }
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="with: items">
  <div id="items" data-bind="template: { foreach: $data }">
    <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: reorder_array">Reorder array</button>
<button data-bind="click: reorder_dom">Reorder DOM</button>
<div>
  Reorder the array twice, then reorder DOM twice. This should work as expected, and end up with the initial state. Then, try to reorder the array again. It should not work. Why?
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/k7u5wep9/1/. The `with` binding refreshes its entire body when its bound value changes, thus causing the `template` binding to be re-inited, instead of differentially updated (use fiddle with and without the `with` binding to see the difference in the console output). Despite 'working' for this example, this will cause performance issues for larger lists, and it doesn't really address the issue head-on.

Comment: I'm fully aware of the performance issues on larger lists and the hackish workaround, but as you said so yourself, you(or the library) are breaking the core rules of using the knockout framework, you should be happy it still kind of works, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

- By manipulating the DOM, you have broken the binding made.
- Do not manipulate directly the DOM. Knockout will not detect the changes made.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is not helpful. As mentioned in the question, I am aware that directly changing the DOM "breaks" knockout. My question is why reverting the DOM does not "fix" it again. I also said that this is out of my control - I can only attempt to revert the DOM state after changes have been made. One would anticipate that this would work, which it does not, and I'd like to know _exactly_ why.